# 2D cache-friendly data structures and space-filling curves

Tags: caching, memory, data-structures, fractals, space-filling-curve

I've read that space-filling curves such as the [Peano curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve) are useful for maintaining cache-friendly data structures in a linear address space, since they maintain physical spatial locality.

However, I'm not sure how to actually use them. Do any of these curves have formulas for quickly translating a linear address into (x,y) coordinates and vice-versa? Otherwise, how do I determine where in memory to look when looking up a certain pair of coordinates? An example would be very helpful.

Comment: The [Z-order curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) has a pretty efficient mapping (just interleave the bits of the coordinates). I've only seen it used for locality-sensitive hashing though, not to actually lay out things in memory.

Comment: @delnan: Oh... is there any that's used to lay things out in memory?

Comment: I never heard of *any* such curve being used to lay things out in memory. Skimming over the Wikipedia article, it appears some people actually did lay out matrices in this order for Strassen's algorithm. I just never heard of it before. I'm pretty skeptical about the benefits in most circumstances, too.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment translate the co-ordinate to a binary and interleave it. Then treat it a base-4 number if you want a quadkey.